# No Water from Reverse Osmosis water system

Tags: plumbing, water, filter, water-filtration, shutoff

I recently replaced my filters and membrane in my Reverse Osmosis water system and now there is no water coming out of the filtration system to the tank. The tank is at the correct pressure, and is empty. If I disconnect the pipe from the tank, while the water is on, there is no water coming out of that pipe. If I disconnect the membrane, I can see there is water getting to it. Could it be the check/shut off valve?

Comment: Filter in backward???

Comment: It takes some screw in filters, not sure if links are welcome on this site, but these are the filters+system http://www.edenfilters.com/moreoswasy50.html

Comment: Was the system working fine before filter change? Do you still have the old cartridges?

Comment: It had been out of operation for about 6 months, we stopped using it because the filters were a year old, and i was less than quick on purchasing new filters, i still have the old cartridges in a bucked somewhere

Comment: I was going to suggest putting old filters back in if the unit was working fine before changing to rule in or out out defective cartridge. There are some pretty good trouble shooting videos on YouTube for RO systems

Comment: https://wateradvise.com/reverse-osmosis-troubleshooting-no-water-or-slow-flow-through-the-faucet/. Check here for starter